# Using trace for Fibonacci

Tags: functions, function-construction, conditional

The Fibonacci function I have constructed is:

`f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]`

`f[0] = 0; f[1] = 1;`

with the first 20 values of the Fibonacci

`Array[f, 20]`

I would like to compute the 5th value of the Fibonacci but with the aid of the `Trace` function. However, I dod not understand the role of this function. No proper/ in depth explanation has been provided by Mathematica.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just apply Trace to the expression you want to see.

```
Clear[f]
f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]
f[0] = 0; f[1] = 1;
Trace[f[3]]
```

[image]

What may be confusing you is the memoization. The code stores the values in a table the first time they are computed. Thus, if you ask for

```
Trace[f[3]]
{f[3],2}
```

a second time, you only get a terse response. This is why I added the `Clear` at the front.

Comment: Hi bill, why is there a hold in the output?

Comment: I see no Hold... try running with a new kernel since that may be due to old definitions.

Comment: I have edited the OP with a shot of the "hold"

Comment: Copy-paste my code (and change the 3 to a 5 if you wish). There is no Hold. You need to restart the kernel. You have some lingering definitions.

Comment: Is there a way to modify my above code to utilise dynamic programming to compute the 200th value of the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: If you want to calculate the nth term for very large n, you can do so via a matrix method that does not need to calculate all the intermediate terms. But dynamic programming seems like overkill.

Comment: @Physkid - If you want to evaluate for large values of `n` just use the built-in [`Fibonacci`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fibonacci.html)  function.  The actual expression for `Fibonacci` can be seen with `Fibonacci[n] // FunctionExpand`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon -- For something counter-intuitive: `Plot[Fibonacci[x], {x, -5, 5}]`

Comment: @bills - see my extended comment

Answer (score 4):

**This is an extended comment rather than an answer**

```
ClearAll[f];
```

Using [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
RSolve[
 {f[n] == f[n - 1] + f[n - 2], f[0] == 0, f[1] == 1},
 f[n], n]

(*  {{f[n] -> Fibonacci[n]}}  *)
```

The [`Fibonacci`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fibonacci.html) function is

```
Fibonacci[n] // FunctionExpand

(*  ((1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^n - (2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n Cos[n π])/Sqrt[5]  *)
```

Looking at the expression for [`GoldenRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GoldenRatio.html)

```
GoldenRatio // FunctionExpand

(*  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])  *)
```

Then

```
Fibonacci[n] == (GoldenRatio^n - GoldenRatio^-n Cos[n Pi])/Sqrt[5] 
   // FunctionExpand

(*  True  *)
```

The recursive definition of the sequence for both positive and negative `n` is

```
f[0] = 0;
f[1] = 1;
f[n_?Positive] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2];
f[n_?Negative] := f[n] = f[n + 2] - f[n + 1];
```

Demonstrating that the sequence lies on the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) of the `Fibonacci` function

```
Plot[Fibonacci[n], {n, -5.2, 5.2},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{#, f[#]} & /@ Range[-5, 5]]}]
```

[image]